# Would changing this code below output a paginated view?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking at this code below:

```
function shortcode_show($atts) {
$attArr = shortcode_atts(array(
    'postid' => 'all', 'num' => 5, 'paginate' => 1, 'perpage' => 5, 'hidecustom' => 0, 'snippet' => 0,
    'more' => '', 'showform' => 1, 'hidereviews' => 0, 'hideresponse' => 0
), $atts);
```

If I change the 'perpage' attribute from 5 to 1, will get an effect something similar to [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByFvl.png)?

I know the styling and etc is a different story, but am I understanding the pagination term correctly?

The plugin in question is [WP Customer Reviews](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customer-reviews/#:%7E:text=WP%20Customer%20Reviews%20allows%20you,choose%20which%20reviews%20get%20shown.)

Comment: Have you tried changing it to see what you get and if it's what you essentially want?

Comment: I wanted to check if I understood the term correctly. The site is live, so if I change it, I do not want anything to break.. So I thought I'd ask here.

I am very new to PHP so still trying to understand what is allowed in the code

Comment: One thing you should definitely do is make a local copy of the site for development where you can tinker freely with whatever settings you wish. In essence, yes, it should display one item per page. But I can't guarantee that's how the plugin works. Your best bet is to try. Even in a live site, you could make the change, see what it looks like and then change it back immediately.

Comment: Thank you @El_Vanja 

I will do that!